# No access to the terminal, how can I find it or install it?

Tags: command-line

So I was uninstalling some programs of mine that I have no use of anymore such as video editors, Skype and Opera. After I completed that, I close my terminal. I realized I needed to install a new program to replace of those that I had deleted, and turns out I can't access my Terminal.

I tried through the xterm, right clicking on my desktop background, through search. Nothing. It's as if it completely disappeared. Just as backup info, I am using Ubuntu 15.10.

UPDATE: I seem to have also lost my Software, Application program. For the life of me I can't remember what it is called, but whatever we use to install programs from Ubuntu seems to have disappeared. I am actually missing some more programs. Is there a way I can revert what I had done?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install synaptic` and/or `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch please write it into an answer, this way it can get accepted if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

To add a graphical package manager, you could do

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

but to globally reinstall the Ubuntu desktop package set you can pass `--reinstall` to `apt-get` like

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 1):

switch to text-based virtual console session 1 to 6 using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>. There you can login with your user account and install what you need.

With <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> your should come back to the x-server or just reboot your machine. Holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is only necessary when switching from the GUI to a text-based virtual console.

Comment: True, but OP mentions that xterm is working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's always TTY virtual consoles : press Ctrl + Alt + F1 , login , and `sudo apt-get install` whatever packages you need, or better yet ( as Elliot Frisch suggested )  `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`. If your system misses even `apt-get` , you may want to use live [media recovery instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Update_Failure) to reinstall everything using live cd